# Not able to access another router setup page

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have two routers, one (Router A) is also the modem connected to the Internet, setup page at 192.168.2.1, DHCP on (range from 192.168.2.5 to 192.168.2.50).

Another (Router B) connects to Router A via LAN cable, assigned IP 192.168.2.2 (fixed). Also DHCP on (range from 192.168.3.10 to 192.168.3.40), its setup page is at 192.168.3.1.

My issue is, when my PC is connected to Router A via LAN cable, assigned IP 192.168.2.3 (fixed), I can access the setup page of Router A at 192.168.2.1, but I can't access the setup page of Router B (tried 192.168.2.2 and 192.168.3.1).

But when my PC is connected to Router B via LAN cable, assigned IP 192.168.3.10, I can access its setup page at 192.168.3.1 AND I can access the setup page of Router A at 192.168.2.1.

I wonder what could be the reason why I can't access the setup page of Router B when my PC is connected to Router A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't access the router setup page on router B while you are connected to router A is that you are you are trying to connect from the WAN side. For security reasons by default you should only be able to access the router setup page from your local network so that people can't try to configure your router from the Internet.

So when you try to connect to 192.168.2.2, The router will not allow you to access the setup page because the connection is coming from the WAN side. You may be able to change this behaviour in the settings for the router.

When you try to connect to 192.168.3.1 you are trying to connect to the private network of router B. Your routers use [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), which basically works like a [stateful firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall) and will not allow connections from the WAN side to connect to the network on the LAN side, unless the connection was established from a machine on the LAN side. This is the reason you can always connect to both router settings pages from the 192.168.3.* network, you are always connecting from the LAN side.